# twisted cycles over fuchsian differential equations 

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm reading about the Gauss [hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) differential equation:
\[  x(1-x)y'' + (c - (a + b + 1)x)y' - aby  =0 \]

Apparently this is a kind of Fuchsian differential equation:
\[ \left(\begin{array}{c}  \frac{dy}{dx} \\\\ \frac{dz}{dx} \end{array} \right)
=  \left(\begin{array}{cc}  0 & 1 \\\\ -ab  & \frac{c_1}{x} + \frac{c_2}{x-1}\end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}  y \\\\z \end{array} \right) \]

whose sections define a [local system](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/04/20/three-ways-of-looking-at-a-local-system-introduction-and-connection-to-cohomology-theories/) over a sphere with 3 punctures, $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0,1 \infty \}$.  We can worry about the monodromy of ODE solutions about these three points $0,1,\infty$.

The paper I'm reading says Fuchsian equations may be is solved by a [Selberg-like integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_integral).

\[  y(x)= \int_\Delta s^{c-b}(s-1)^{c-a-1} (s-x)^{-b} \, ds \]

Where the integral is over a "[twisted cycle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/twisted+cohomology)" $\Delta$ in $H_1(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{ 0,1,x\}, L^* )$.

---

My trouble is understanding what these twisted cycles look like.  The local system $L^*$ is dual to the local system $L$ generated by sections $s \mapsto  s^{c-b}(s-1)^{c-a-1} (s-x)^{-b} $, which is multivalued.  The values form a discrete set with (possibly countably) many fibers over a point in $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{ 0,1,x\}$ so $L$ should be dual to a branched cover over the three-punctured sphere possibly with more information.   Then maybe $H_1(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{ 0,1,x\}, L^*)$ is the collection of loops in this branched cover.

**How is $H_1(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{ 0,1,x\}, L^*)$ different from $H_1(\mathbb{C}\backslash\{ 0,1,x\})$ ?**